SwiftUI: Close popover sheet return me to unexpected destination
I am developing an ios app using swift.I am on xcode 15.3 now
I have a problem with NavigationView
Let's say my app have 2 pages (page A,page B) and a popover sheet C
I wrapped my whole app with NavigationView().
//Page A
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Main()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

From page A I can navigate to page B clicking a button
//Page B  
NavigationLink(
                destination: LookupFlightPage().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true),
                tag: 1,
                selection: $clickItem) {
                CategoryItem(icon: "airplane.circle", name: "Flights").onTapGesture {
                    clickItem = 1
                }
            }

From page B I can open the popover sheet C
BottomLineControl(label: "From", icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "airplane")
                }, searchText: searchedData.from, onTap: {
                    popoverOpen1 = true
                }).sheet(isPresented: $popoverOpen1, content: {
                    FlightSearch(popoverOpen: $popoverOpen1, dataChanged: $searchedData.from)
                })

And In C, I can cancel the sheet to be back to page B(set binding state popoverOpen1 = false).BUT the problem is when I canceled the sheet C, it brought me to page A.
HStack {
                SearchField(searchText: "")
                Text("Cancel").font(.system(size: 14.0)).foregroundColor(.white).onTapGesture {
                    popoverOpen = false
                }
            }

The problem occurred when I had updated my xcode 12.x to xcode 15.3.Everything was good back in the older version.So I think it might be due to some usage of NavigationView
Thank you

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve], ideally something that can be pasted into Xcode to reproduce your problem.

NavigationView has been deprecated for years, unless you have an extraordinary reason for supporting iOS13-15 switch to NavigationStack

I am not in ios 16 yet, so I guess NavigationView is the only choice I have ?

I found out the problem was down to the version under 16.0 ios and using TabView with NavigationView.You should not wrap the whole app when using with Tabview but wrap each Tab with the NavView separately.And it is not the case with ver 16.0 and higher
